# How to interpret ACF and PACF in time series?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, autocorrelation, acf-pacf, partial-correlation

In this following monthly sales time series, how can I interpret ACF and PACF?

STL Decomposition
[image]

ACF:

[image]

PACF:
[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://otexts.com/fpp3/acf.html) and [this](https://otexts.com/fpp3/non-seasonal-arima.html#non-seasonal-arima) (search for "ACF and PACF plots") help?

Comment: No, I already read them but did not get much. What I need is an economic interpretation rather than a technical one.

Comment: Hm. There is not really anything *economic* about the ACF/PACF. They are measures of correlation of a time series with lagged values of itself (corrected for intermediate dependencies in the case of PACF). What economic interpretation would you assign to a "normal" correlation?

Comment: For instance, how can I explain these to someone who does not know much about this technical analysis? Let's say a store hired you to analyze their monthly sales, you got this result but you can't just give these plots since they don't make sense for them. What does it mean for store owner? What is the interpretation?

Comment: I don't think I would give ACF/PACF plots to a nontechnical store owner, at least not to one who is unprepared to invest the time and effort to understand the technique (not necessarily at great details). What is your goal? Are you forecasting, and the audience needs to understand the forecast? If so, explain that you essentially feed past sales into your model, which helps explain future sales. It's probably not necessary to show *how* you decide which lags to use, using ACF/PACF plots. (Incidentally, modern forecasting methods don't really use ACF/PACF any more.)

Comment: Actually, my goal is not forecasting. I just exploring patterns in the time series data. Therefore as I guess I don't need ACF/PACF, right?

Comment: Then ACF/PACF probably makes sense. However, this is such a technical level of explanation that I don't think you can really explain this to a nontechnical audience (beyond "correlations of the series with itself").